# angular 2.0 beta import {bootstrap}

Tags: angular

```
import {bootstrap}    from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Is it importing UI bootstrap.js or is this for bootstrapping angular. What does these lines of code actually do?

Comment: last line means this is your entry point to the app. which is being bootstraped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first two lines make the declarations of `bootstrap` and `AppComponent` known in the current file.

The 3rd line invokes (bootstraps) your Angular2 application with `AppComponent` as root component.

Theoretically the TS tools could look up the declarations in your project directory but if there were more than one declaration with the same name (common scenario) the tools had a hard time to figure out which one you meant.

With explicit imports this is made clear and makes it easier for tools to provide additional support like auto-completion, linter warnings, optimized transpilation (tree-shaking, minification),...

Comment: Did `bootstrap` indicates UI bootstrap JS files?

Comment: Angulars `bootstrap` isn't related to the Bootstrap CSS/JS UI widgets library at all. The name similarity is incidentally.

Comment: Thank u @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: i think `bootstrap` here in `anguar2` is slimier to `ng-app` in the angular1.